# treeview class binding

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I am newbie on c#.
I want to make a treeview with having point positions data.
It's treeview looks like following..

Form1 (parent)
Triangle1 (child1)
Triangle2 (child2)

If I cliked Triangle1 then I want to have Triangle1's coord informations.
But when I maked triangle class and tried to input treeview node..then that makes error..
how can I solve this problem?

---

addition..
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public class BigCanvas
        {
            public string Id;
            public string Name;
        }

```
    public class Triangle
    {
        public string Id;
        public string Name;
        public Point point1;
        public Point point2;
        public Point point3;
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Name = "Draw Triangle";
        this.Text = "Draw sample";
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BigCanvas bc1 = new BigCanvas();
        bc1.Id = "0";
        bc1.Name = "sample1";
        Triangle ta1 = new Triangle();
        ta1.Id = "01";
        ta1.Name = "triangle1";
        ta1.point1 = new Point(30, 50);
        ta1.point2 = new Point(40,60);
        ta1.point3 = new Point(70,80);

        TreeNode root = treeView1.Nodes.Add(bc1);  // error
        root.Nodes.Add(ta1); // error
        root.Nodes.Add(ta2); // error
    }

    private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode current = e.Node;

        // Draw with triangle point           
    }
```

But I can't add Triangle class to TreeNode!! ... then what is alternative solve to this problem..?

Comment: Thanks for advice Grant Winney. I add some code and explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your node to tree:

```
class MyNode: TreeNode
{
    public string AnotherName { get; set; }
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public MyNewObjectType NewObject{ get; set; }
    .
    .
}

Tree.Nodes.Add(MyNode);
```

or use Tag property of Node.

```
node1.Tag = MyClass;
Tree.Nodes.Add(node1);
```